# C callback functions defined in an unnamed namespace?

Tags: c++, calling-convention, linkage

I have a C++ project that uses a C bison parser. The C parser uses a struct of function pointers to call functions that create proper AST nodes when productions are reduced by bison:

```
typedef void Node;
struct Actions {
  Node *(*newIntLit)(int val);
  Node *(*newAsgnExpr)(Node *left, Node *right);
  /* ... */
};
```

Now, in the C++ part of the project, i fill those pointers

```
class AstNode {
  /* ... */
};
class IntLit : public AstNode { 
  /* ... */
};

extern "C" {
  Node *newIntLit(int val) {
    return (Node*)new IntLit(val);
  }

  /* ... */
}

Actions createActions() {
  Actions a;
  a.newIntLit = &newIntLit;
  /* ... */
  return a;
}
```

Now the only reason i put them within `extern "C"` is because i want them to have C calling conventions. But optimally, i would like their names still be mangled. They are never called by-name from C code, so name mangling isn't an issue. Having them mangled will avoid name conflicts, since some actions are called like `error`, and the C++ callback function has ugly names like the following just to avoid name clashes with other modules.

```
extern "C" {
  void uglyNameError(char const *str) {
    /* ... */
  }

  /* ... */
}

a.error = &uglyNameError;
```

I wondered whether it could be possible by merely giving the function type C linkage

```
extern "C" void fty(char const *str);
namespace {
  fty error; /* Declared! But i can i define it with that type!? */
}
```

Any ideas? I'm looking for Standard-C++ solutions.

Comment: Can’t you compile the Bison output as C++ code, thus avoiding the problem altogether?

Comment: @Konrad my colleague said that bison C++ mode isn't nice to work with, and so we do that part with pure C and have it abstracted, so together with the scanner makes up a pure C library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get the problem.  The extern keyword does not affect the calling convention, merely the name presented to the linker.  A function written in C++ that is not an instance method is still __cdecl, with or without extern "C".  Furthermore, as long as you keep createActions() in the same source code file, these functions don't need external linkage.  You could declare them static or put them in an unnamed namespace to avoid collisions.

Comment: Ah, i could make then `static`. Good idea, why didn't i think of that :) I only thought of unnamed namespaces, but that won't do anything to their linkage and won't prevent clashes for `extern "C"` functions. But `static` could actually work! For the remaining parts of your answer: It can make a difference to calling convention if the implementation wishes to do so. I wanted to not depend on any particular implementation, so i made them `extern "C"`.